# rails 3.2 bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

If i click on my dropdown menu, nothing is happening...

here some lines of code:

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %> 
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", media: "all" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= favicon_link_tag %>
```

**app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "Something", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <ul class="nav pull-right noline">
      <li><%= link_to "Docs",  '/home' %></li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown bold">
            <a href="#fat-menu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <%= current_user.username %><b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you try adding this `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` in your js file ?

Comment: i've added it to application.js but no change jet

Comment: It is added in `document.ready` block ?

Comment: no.. what is the correct syntax to add it there?

Comment: at the momoent not...

Comment: Which versions of jQuery and Bootstrap you use?

Comment: Using jquery-rails (2.2.1)
Using bootstrap-sass (2.0.0)

Comment: Could you try updating `bootstrap-sass` to the latest version?

Comment: Yeah thank you !! but why is the sam versin running correctly in my other app with the sam dropdowns??

Comment: You will look at my code and tell me did you have the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** it seems that `bootstrap-sass` gem at version `2.0.0` provides Twitter Bootstrap that is using outdated `$.browser` property. So update it to the latest version (`2.2.2` as for now).

Change the order of directives in `application.js` to this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

** important to follow the sequence~

//= require_tree .
is the last thing to be required.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried other answer ? Do you see errors in Chrome console or Firebug ?

Comment: if i load the site, firebug console sais: TypeError: $.browser is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

if ( $.browser.webkit ) {

Comment: is not working either... do you need other information as the given?

Comment: You have bootstrap-dropdown.js in your assets folder ?

Comment: this file is loaded correctly: Started GET "/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-29 11:28:22 +0100
Served asset /bootstrap-dropdown.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Comment: ok, it should be easy, so i will create my own app and add bootstrap.js and write t you what steps I made.

Comment: that would be perfect.. cause i have another app working with nearly the same code :(

Comment: If I upload myapp into github and describe how it work it will be ok for you ?

Comment: I added `bootstrap-sass` gem in my Gemfile and after bundle added `@import "bootstrap";` in *.css.scss file

Comment: Please download this following this link - http://www.ex.ua/view_storage/565925214017, because I have problems with ssh key and I don't want to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include something like this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui" %>
```

I can't remmember for sure, but try to include those files if they are not. Make sure they are in asset/javascript folder

I mean this is just an example, you can include them in `application.js` as well

Comment: should i try this with the old version?

Comment: @HappyHacking I doubt downgrading will fix anything. Stupid question: did you reset your server? In configuration have you put `assets:precompile` to `true` ? and do you have mentioned files in `assets/javascript` , or if they are compiled in `public/javascript`? And have you run `rake assets:precompile`? - That is all possible options that I can think of right away

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Fixed it by changing the version of bootstrap I was using to ->

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

I answer a similar issue, dropdown-menu also not triggerd, but which is only occured on myself.

```
<a href="#" ,class="dropdown-toggle" ,data-toggle="dropdown">
```

Yes,it is just a syntax error.
I have not used HTML language in my works before.

wtf.

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
```

Emmm,and if you read the Rails tutorial book by Micheal Heart too and modified code by other questions's solves,well,turn them to origin code.